# Owners of single entity and owners of group of entities. Constraints or relationship?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, domain-driven-design, relationship

Easy model. Three simple main entities: **Task**, **Owner**, **TasksGroup**.

- Many **Owners** might have many **Tasks** and opposite (many-to-many).
- **Task** can optionally belong to only one **TasksGroup**, but **TasksGroup** might have many **Tasks**(one-to-many)

And now the tricky part for me. **Owners** of each **Task** within **TasksGroup** must be the same. There would be also possibility to change **Owners** of all **Tasks** within **TasksGroup**, or of single **Task** if it doesn't belong to any **TasksGroup**.

Should there be check constraints? Or maybe there should be "master" relationship established between **TasksGroup** and **Owners**? What about relation between **Task** and **Owners** if **Task** belongs to group? What is the good way to design this?

Answer (score 1):

A common strategy in this kind of model is to simplify it by requiring each Task to belong to a TaskGroup.  This enables you to remove the direct relationship between a Task and an Owner, at the cost of having single-Task TaskGroups to for stand-alone Tasks.

Comment: Thanks David, that's an interesting approach. But I'm afraid in my scenario it would complicate distinguishing between tasks that belong to group, and the ones that are standalone. There can be case when actually "real" group has only one task.

Comment: In EF Core you could have one FK Task -> TaskGroup on (TaskGroupID,OwnerId), and a separate one Task -> Owner on (OwnerID).  But that has its own complexities.

Answer (score 1):

> Owners of each Task within TasksGroup must be the same

Enforcing this by database constraints can be done by first defining a junction class/table between `Task` and `Owner`, `TaskOwner`, which is standard in a many-to-many relationship.

If a `TaskGroup` must be restricted to tasks of one owner, the natural place to connect it to is where information of tasks and owners is available, i.e. the junction table. Doing that by just one FK, say `GroupId`, isn't enough though. The `TaskGroup` itself must be constrained to one owner. It requires an `OwnerId` that is part of its PK, so `TaskOwner` can refer to it by `OwnerId` and `GroupId`. Finally, `TaskGroup`s `OwnerId` must be a FK to `Owner` to make sure that `TaskOwner` and `TaskGroup` refer to the same owner. That amounts to this database model:

[image]

> There would be also possibility to change Owners of all Tasks within TasksGroup

As often, strict constraints and flexibility are mutually exclusive. This ring of `OwnerId` references is hard to break. `OwnerId` in `TaskOwner` must be changed, but that requires four steps:

- set `GroupId` to `null`
- change `OwnerId`
- change the `TaskGroup`'s `OwnerId`
- restore `TaksOwner.GroupId`

Complicated enough with SQL, but even harder with Entity Framework, because EF doesn't allow modification of primary key properties. With EF you have to delete `TaskOwner`s, create new ones and then set `TaskGroup.OwnerId` and `TaskOwner.GroupId`. Not impossible, but all but flexible!

Comment: This design seems to allow multiple groups per task, and multiple owners per group.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with having `RequiredOwners` of sorts on the `TaskGroup`.  In fact, one may even have different types of `TaskGroup` instances where one type requires assigned tasks to have the corresponding owners where others may have different rules.  However, that depends on the domain so if this is a real domain you are referring to you would know :)

But it really would be the easiest implementation by have the task group have a list of owners.  Well, the `TaskGroup` would contain either the Ids or a list of value objects representing the owners.  Managing the owner assignments on tasks may even be driven from the task group once it is configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple schema plus a general database constraint, if your DBMS supports those (and the resulting performance is tolerable). Most don't, unfortunately.

Apart from that, the cleanest approach is overlapping foreign (super)keys. Here is a pseudocode relational approach that doesn't require NULLs; data types and uninteresting attributes omitted:

```
create table Task {
  TaskId,
  key { TaskId }
};

create table Owner {
  OwnerId,
  key { OwnerId }
};

create table TaskOwner { /* Bog standard association table */
  TaskId,
  OwnerId,
  key { Taskid, OwnerId }
  reference TO_T { TaskId } references Task { TaskId },
  reference TO_O { OwnerId } references Owner { OwnerId }
};

create table TaskGroup {
  GroupId,
  OwnerId,
  key { GroupId }, /* Each group has exactly one owner */
  reference TG_O { OwnerId } references Owner { OwnerId }
};

create table TaskGroupTask {
  TaskId,
  GroupId,
  OwnerId,
  key { TaskId }, /* Each task may belong to at most one group */
  reference TGT_TO { TaskId, OwnerId } references TaskOwner { TaskId, OwnerId },
  /* Foreign superkey coming up */
  reference TGT_TG { GroupId, OwnerId } references TaskGroup { Group, OwnerId }
};
```

The clue is that `TaskGroupTask.Ownerid` does double duty as part of the references to both `TaskOwner` and `TaskGroup`, and thereby ensures that the owner of the group is identical to the owner of each task in it. There is a foreign superkey here—`TGT_TG` refers to a superset of `TaskGroup`'s key—but if your DBMS objects to this, a possible workaround is to create a (superfluous) unique index on the superset.

Having a separate `TaskGroupTask` table instead of a nullable `TaskOwner.GroupId` attribute may on first glance seem like overkill, but it allows you to use a simple key constraint to enforce the rule that a task may belong to at most one group. Plus it avoids NULLs.

There is a functional dependency `{ GroupId } -> { OwnerId }` in `TaskGroupTask` that violates Boyce-Codd normal form, but the redundancy is controlled by the `TGT_TG`reference, and it is necessary to enforce the rules of the situation.

Changing the owner of a group (and all its tasks) involves updating three tables in the same statement/transaction, but a proper RDBMS should have no problem with this.

This design does allow a task to belong to multiple owners *and* be in one group at the same time, creating a situation where all tasks in a group belong to the same owner, but they belong to other owners (though not groups) as well. It is unclear from your question if this is a problem, so let me know if it is. The design also disallows groups without owners, but I assume this is ok.